# is `return_if_null(T* ptr)` possible?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

I'm finding myself doing a lot of

```cpp
void doSomethingCool(CoolObject* coolObject) {
   if (coolObject == nullptr) {
      return;
   }

   // now _actually_ do something cool
}
```

I thought about macros, but it felt a bit gross...

```cpp
// plus some other templating for other return types, but besides the point
#define RETURN_IF_NULL(nullable) if (nullable == null) { return; }

void doSomethingCool(CoolObject* coolObject) {
   RETURN_IF_NULL(coolObject)

   // now _actually_ do something cool
}
```

It would be cool to have something like `std::return_if_null<T>`, like this

```cpp
#include <early_return>

void doSomethingCool(CoolObject* coolObject) {
   std::return_if_null(coolObject);

   // now _actually_ do something cool
}
```

I don't think this is possible with C++ as it is now, but would be keen to hear if you think this could work, or if you think it would be an interesting language feature.

Edit, full context, what I would looove to see is something like this.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ReturnType>
std::early_return<ReturnType> return_if_null(T* ptr, ReturnType defaultValue = {}) {
   static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<T>());
   if (ptr == nullptr) {
     return std::early_return::abort{defaultValue};
   }
   return std::early_return::continue;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Avoid this hell and pass around pointers, null or otherwise, as little as possible.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you're right. Only pretty sure because every time I say "It can't be done" someone slaps me with an insane template. Even if it was standardized, it would have to be a macro or some new deep magic. Just use the macro. It's almost certainly simpler than the insane template that's lurking out there, waiting to surprise me.

Comment: There's already something in C++ that's pretty much a pointer that can never be null, making this whole thing moot. It's called a "reference". Have you considered getting some help for resolving the common "Pointless Use Of Pointers" malady, that causes this?

Comment: Come to think of it, you could reverse the logic, `do_not_call_if_null(doSomethingCool, coolObject);`, without much trouble.

Comment: @user4581301 that's a cool idea actually lol.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah this is also true wrt references... there are some places where 3rd party libraries pass us pointers, so that's why we're doing a bit of pointer checking.

Comment: It's kinda unusual to just return if a parameter is null. Surely if the function *needs* it, than it's a programming error to pass nullptr for the parameter. If it's a programming error then we can `assert` on it.

Comment: If your function only works if you have an actual object, then you want `void doSomethingCool(/*const*/ CoolObject& coolObject)`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `std::free` / `delete` does follow that pattern. But I agree that it seems rarely useful.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you're stuck with pointers. And you're a fool if you **don't** check them. That said usually when I get a null pointer back from an API call the clean-up logic is more extensive than returning early or not calling a function. More often than not the null return means stuff went wrong and at the very least there's some logging of breadcrumbs .

Answer (score 3):

> is `return_if_null(T* ptr)` possible?

No.

> I thought about macro

Ok, that is possible. But don't.

---

It's somewhat unclear why you want this, but if you're exploring different styles, you can write the function like this:

```
void doSomethingCool(CoolObject* coolObject) {
   if (coolObject) {
      // now _actually_ do something cool
   }
}
```

But it's of course a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah that is kind of what I expected to hear lol. Trying to keep our codebase to the pattern of early returning from a style perspective, since we believe it's cleaner / more readable. Do you think this would be an interesting/cool/helpful feature though?

Comment: Some people prefer early return to nested ifs that can lead to arrow antipatterns.

Comment: @QuentinUK Indeed. I would write `if (!coolObject) return;` myself.

Comment: @JamiePond `Do you think this would be an interesting/cool/helpful feature though?` No. `Trying to keep our codebase to the pattern of early returning from a style perspective, since we believe it's cleaner / more readable.` You don't need this feature for that. You can use if and return statements as you did in your first example.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this probably isn't what you are looking for, but coroutines are malleable enough to largely mimic this.

First we define a wrapper type for pointers that you want a null-check for:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct return_if_null {
    return_if_null(T ptr) : ptr(ptr) {} 
    T ptr;
    operator T() const { return ptr; }
};
```

And a way to identify that wrapper:

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_return_if_null = false;

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_return_if_null<return_if_null<T>> = true;
```

Next we specialize `coroutine_traits` for coroutines that return `void` and has at least one `return_if_null` parameter:

```cpp
template<class...Ts>
requires (is_return_if_null<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>> || ...)
struct std::coroutine_traits<void, Ts...> {
    struct promise_type { 
        /* ... */ 
        bool return_early;
    };
};
```

And then we use the parameter preview to fill `return_early` in the promise type constructor:

```cpp
        template<class T>
        bool is_null_return_if_null(T& t){
            if constexpr (is_return_if_null<std::remove_cv_t<T>>){
                return t.ptr == nullptr;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        template<class... Us>
        promise_type(Us&&... args) {
            return_early = (is_null_return_if_null(args) || ...);
        }
```

Now `initial_suspend`: if we need to return early, we suspend the coroutine, destroy the coroutine frame, and return to the caller. Otherwise, we let the coroutine continue execution:

```cpp
        auto initial_suspend() {
            struct A {
                void await_resume() {}
                bool await_ready() {
                    return not return_early;
                }
                void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
                    h.destroy();
                }
                bool return_early;
            };
            return A{return_early};
        }
```

The remaining coroutine boilerplate:

```cpp
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() { throw; }
        void await_transform() = delete; // don't allow co_await
        void return_void(){}
```

And now to use it:

```cpp
void f(return_if_null<int*> ptr) {
    // won't get here if ptr is null
    std::cout << "function body here\n";
    co_return;
}
```

(You do need at least one `co_return` in the body to make it an actual coroutine.)

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eK8Gd8MTG).

It is also possible to make `co_await return_if_null(ptr);` work (instead of having everything magically happen at the initial suspension point), but you'll still need some kind of hook in the signature so that you can provide a special promise type.